# Group by count in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, count

In pandas dataframe I want to create two new columns that would calculate count the occurrence of the same value and a third column that would calculate the ratio

ratio = count_occurrence_both_columns /count_occurrence_columnA *100

df = pd.DataFrame({"column A": ["Atlanta", "Atlanta", "New York", "New York","New York"], "column B": ["AT", "AT", "NY", "NY", "AT"]})
df

| columnA | ColumnB | occurrence_columnA | occurrence_both_columns | Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Atlanta | AT | 2 | 2 | 100% |
| Atlanta | AT | 2 | 2 | 100% |
| Newyork | NY | 3 | 2 | 66.66% |
| Newyork | NY | 3 | 2 | 66.66% |
| Newyork | AT | 3 | 1 | 33.33% |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can create a dictionary that has the keys as column A unique values and the values as the count.

```
>>> column_a_mapping = df['column A'].value_counts().to_dict()
>>> column_a_mapping
>>> {'New York': 3, 'Atlanta': 2}
```

Then, you can create a new column that has the two columns merged in order to have the same value counts dictionary as above.

```
>>> df['both_columns'] = (
        df[['column A', 'column B']]
        .apply(lambda row: '_'.join(row), axis=1)
    )

>>> both_columns_mapping = df['both_columns'].value_counts().to_dict()
>>> both_columns_mapping
>>> {'New York_NY': 2, 'Atlanta_AT': 2, 'New York_AT': 1}
```

Once you have the unique values count, you can simple use the `replace` `pd.Series` method.

```
>>> df['count_occurrence_both_columns'] = df['both_columns'].replace(both_columns_mapping)
>>> df['count_occurrence_columnA'] = df['column A'].replace(column_a_mapping)
```

Lastly, you can drop the column that has both columns merged and then create you ratio column with:

```
>>> df['ratio'] = df['count_occurrence_both_columns'] / df['count_occurrence_columnA'] * 100
>>> df.drop('both_columns', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

You should obtain this dataframe:

| column A | column B | count_occurrence_columnA | count_occurrence_both_columns | ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Atlanta | AT | 2 | 2 | 100.000000 |
| Atlanta | AT | 2 | 2 | 100.000000 |
| New York | NY | 3 | 2 | 66.666667 |
| New York | NY | 3 | 2 | 66.666667 |
| New York | AT | 3 | 1 | 33.333333 |

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas groupby to count the items

```
df['occurrence_columnA'] = df.groupby(['column A'])['column B'].transform(len)
df['occurrence_both_columns'] = df.groupby(['column A','column B'])['occurrence_columnA'].transform(len)
```

The alternative way is to use **transform('count')** but this will ignore NaN's